# need to require gem in the application even though gemspec adds it as a runtime dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem say 'A' is used in the gem and the gemspec file adds a runtime dependency saying

s.add_dependency 'A', '~> 1.0'

I get an error saying some file/class was not found the in the gem when I run my application. This error goes away when I include the gem in the applications Gemfile.

Why should I need to include the gem in the application despite it being a runtime dependency?

Answer (score 4):

This is just how gem dependencies work. When you add a dependency it doesn’t automatically require the depended on gem (in fact it can’t because there is no way of knowing the filename to require — not all gems have the same name as their main file).

Adding a dependency to a gem has two effects. First, when you install the gem the depended on gems are also installed automatically.

Second, when the gem is *activated* (which normally happens when you `require` a file from it, but can be done explicitly with [`gem`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem)) the gem’s lib dir is added to the load path, and so are the lib dirs of any dependencies. This ensures that when the main gem calls `require` on these dependencies the correct version will be used.

The main gem still needs to call `require` on its dependencies. There is no way in general for Rubygems to know which file from the gem should be required, or when (or even if) it should happen. For example a dependency may only be needed in certain cases, so you want to avoid calling require (which would slow you down) unless you actually needed the functionality provided.

Comment: This is kind of confusing . How come we don't require when we add gem dependencies in gemfile .

Comment: @Vinay You _do_ need to `require` when using a Gemfile with Bundler, but Bundler provides a `Bundler.require` method as a convenience, which requires all of the gems in your Gemfile. Rails uses this by default (check your `config/application.rb` file if you’re using Rails), so all the dependencies are required when your call `Bundler.require`. (Note that Rubygems and Bundler are separate libraries (at least currently, there is talk Bundler being included in Rubygems in the future)).